# downloading error in youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

While trying to download a video from youtube using youtube.dl I got the following error:

```
WARNING: unable to extract uploader nickname
ERROR: Signature extraction failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 905, in _decrypt_signature
    video_id, player_url, s
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 797, in _extract_signature_function
    raise ExtractorError('Cannot identify player %r' % player_url)
ExtractorError: Cannot identify player u'/yts/jsbin/player-vfluepRD8/en_US/base.js'; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
 (caused by ExtractorError(u"Cannot identify player u'/yts/jsbin/player-vfluepRD8/en_US/base.js'; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.",)); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

What could it mean?